# Filling in a grid without using graphics libraries (tkinter or pygame)

Tags: python

Like I said in the title, I have an assignment where I need to make three grids and fill in certain coordinates.

I have written this code to make the grid:

```
def display_grid(lines,columns,grid):
  print("Grid",grid,":")
  i = 0
  print("  | ",end="")
  for column in range(columns):
    i += 1
    print(i,end=" | ")
  
  print()
  for column in range((columns+1)*2):
    print("-",end=" ")
  
  print()
  letter = 64

  for line in range(lines):
    letter += 1
    print(chr(letter),end=" |  ")
    for column in range(columns):
      print(" |  ",end="")
    print()
    for column in range((columns+1)*2):
      print("-",end=" ")
    print()

  print()

display_grid(9,9,1)
```

Output:
[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oot3E.png)

This code does work and it displays a grid, however now I need to write a function that would fill in a specific square. Something like `fill(3,6)`, and it would fill in the F3 square.

I assume I will have to modify the base program somehow. Not sure where to go from here so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how you would identify the F3 square in your code. For example, if you wanted to always print an `X` for the F3 square how would you do that? Once you can do that, then you can refactor your code so that you can pick any square to print an `X`. You could take it a step further to allow a list of squares to be printed at.

I hope this helps you get started. Best of luck!